# wp_add_inline_script isn't adding anything to my page, can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to add inline script to just a single page, so trying to add in the page template file. However, both placements of the code above or below the footer call results in nothing being outputted in the source.

I can't figure out how this is supposed to work, can anyone help?

** Page Template **

```
<?php
get_footer('blank');
function cardpay_demo_script() {
    wp_add_inline_script(
        'jquery',
        '$(".btn-next").click(function() {
            $(".nav-pills .active").parent().next("li").find("a").removeClass("disabled").trigger("click");
        });'
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cardpay_demo_script');
```

** Footer File **

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are placing the function on the wrong file. 
The function should go on the theme's **functions.php** file and not **any default template file or your custom template file**.

The reason for this is that in WordPress; an Action is a PHP function that is executed at specific points throughout the WordPress Core and since your custom templates will be called way after the hook has been triggered the function will never actually run, so it won't print anything.

You can use `is_page()` or `is_page_template()` to determine if it is the page or page template you're looking for.

Here is some additional information on action hooks: https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Action

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
   if( !is_page_template('My Template') ) return;
   if ( ! wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
     wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   }
   wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery', '$(".btn-next").click(function() { $(".nav-pills .active").parent().next("li").find("a").removeClass("disabled").trigger("click");
        });' );
});
```

or you can just print your scripts on the footer using the **wp_footer** hook. Just put this on your theme's **functions.php** file

```
add_action('wp_footer', function (){ 
   if( !is_page_template('My Template') ) return;
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(".btn-next").click(function() { jQuery(".nav-pills .active").parent().next("li").find("a").removeClass("disabled").trigger("click");
            });
    </script>

<?php   
});
```